# Not getting results more than 10 by using ForwardGeocodeOptions in MAPBOX SDK

Tags: ios, mapbox, mapbox-marker

I am implementing `ForwardGeocodeOptions` in my `iOS` sample app using **MAPBOX SDK**. And I am making a call for getting Placemarks. But always getting 10 results only. I want to get minimum 30 results or more than that. How can I get ?

```
func getResults(){

    let options = ForwardGeocodeOptions(query: "restaurant")
   // options.allowedISOCountryCodes = ["IN"]
    options.focalLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 17.4447496, longitude: 78.3136091)
    options.allowedScopes = [.pointOfInterest,.all]
    options.maximumResultCount = 50
    let task = Geocoder.shared.geocode(options) {(placemarks, attribution, error) in
        if let error = error {
            NSLog("%@", error)
        } else if let placemarks = placemarks, !placemarks.isEmpty {
             print(" \(placemarks.count)")               

        }
    }
    task.resume()
}
```

Internally calling this API :-

- https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/restaurant.json?proximity=78.3817464,17.446809&types=all&limit=50&access_token=[access_token_here]

Answer (score 0):

Per the [API docs](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#request-format), 10 is the upper limit for a forward geocoding request. You’re free to make multiple requests with different parameters.